# Kotlin Can MutableList<Any> can savedInstanceState()

Tags: android, listview

In Android Kotlin is it possible to do `savedInstanceState()` with `MutableList<Any>` object ?

If possible please share how, or what should the way to solve this ?

the problem is `MutableList<Any>` contain different object for differentiate `itemViewType for ListView`